# Empty lines from Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

Almost there ;)
I´m trying to implement Jquery Autocomplete to an input field.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="objekt_nr">
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#objekt_nr" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'php/ajaxGetObjNr.php',
        minLength: 3,
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$return = array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $return[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($return);
```

**Result in Browser Console**

```
[{objekt_nr: "22133-01"}, {objekt_nr: "22135-13-3"}, {objekt_nr: "22135-2-4"},…]
```

But when i type for ex: 221 in the input field, it suggest alot of empty white lines...
Why is that?

In the autocomplete docs it says its compatibale with Json?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery autocomplete expects the response to be in one of two [formats](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), either an array of strings:

```
[
    "22133-01",
    "22135-13-3",
    "22135-2-4"
]
```

or an array of objects that have at least a `label` or a `value` property (or both!):

```
[
    {
        "label": "Object 1",
        "value": "22133-01"
    },
    {
        "label": "Object 2",
        "value": "22135-13-3"
    },
    {
        "label": "Object 3",
        "value": "22135-2-4"
    }
]
```